# Given a function $\phi$ and the set of iterates $(\phi^t)$ under self-composition, can you construct $\phi^t $ for a real continuous parameter?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, functions

$\phi$ is given as any function with the following properties:
1. $\phi$ is strictly increasing
2. $\phi$ is continuous
3. $\phi$ is a mapping of the interval $[0,1]$ into itself.
4. $\phi^n\circ\phi^m = \phi^{n+m} = \phi^{m+n}$
5. $\phi^0 = x$ is the identity map.

Consider the set $S$ of all $\phi$'s self-iterates, denoted $S = \{\phi^t : \forall t \in\mathbb{Z}^+\}$. In case it is unclear what I mean by $\phi^t$, or self-iterates, here are some examples:
  $\phi^1(x) = \phi(x)$
  $\phi^2(x) = \phi^1\circ\phi^1(x)$
  $\phi^3(x) = \phi^1\circ\phi^1\circ\phi^1(x) = \phi^2\circ\phi^1(x) = \phi^1\circ\phi^2(x)$

QUESTION: Given the definitions above, is it possible to construct  $\phi^t$ for a real non-negative continuous parameter $t$, such that the new set $S' = \{\phi^t : \forall t \in\mathbb{R}^+\}$ is isomorphic to the non-negative real numbers under multiplication?

**Comments: I am an undergraduate and I honestly don't even feel like I understand the problem well enough to propose a strategy for proving it, let alone a formal proof. If anyone could explain the problem itself in less technical terms I would really appreciate it, but for the time being I have no clue how to proceed. My professor suggested splitting $\phi$ into piece-wise linear components, but he didn't say what to do after that.

***Final note: If at all possible I would really appreciate if you "dumbed-down" any explanations to an undergraduate level for me. Please assume that I don't know anything beyond undergraduate analysis and abstract algebra. This is my first question on this site, so I'm sorry if I didn't format something the right way or follow etiquette.

Comment: I am confused as to how this can possibly be true, since $S$ is countable and $\mathbb{R}^+$ is not.

Comment: Echo @EthanAlwaise. $S$ is countable because it is generated by positive integer, while non-negative real is not. Also, are you sure we are concerning with *non-negative* real under *multiplication*?

Comment: I am puzzled, I would think that "non-negative Reals under multiplication" should have been "non-negative Integers under addition." The only think I could think of is take an example e.g. $\varphi(x)=\dfrac x2$ and read the problem again to see if it makes sense. Then one might indeed say $\varphi^{\frac p q}(x)=(\dfrac12)^{\frac p q}\cdot x$, but that would be an extension, something extra, if and when it could be done, but not done by default, so perhaps clarify the statement one more time with your teacher.

Comment: You were all correct, I did not pose the question correctly, because I didn't really understand it -- but having to figure out where I went wrong was hugely instructive, so thanks